# How to decouple data between microservices?

Tags: architecture, microservices

Here is a scenario I need help to solve.

-> means dependency

Service A -> Service B

Services contain their own databases.

The one way dependency is ok. But now I have requirement where I have data that is only used in Service A but belongs against records in B and this data needs to be created at the time the record is created in Service B.

This will cause any changes to the data structure required By A will also be required in B resulting in tight coupling.

What approach can I take to solve this data coupling?

Answer (score 1):

For this

> The one way dependency is ok. But now I have requirement where I have data that is only used in Service A but belongs against records in B and this data needs to be created at the time the record is created in Service B.

You should consider event sourcing. When the record is being created in Service B, an event should be published e.g. `RecordInBCreated` containing that record. Service A will be subscribed to listen that event. Once an event is published by B and listened by A, you can do whatever with that event data inside Service A. In this way you don't have to worry much about this:

> This will cause any changes to the data structure required By A will also be required in B resulting in tight coupling.